# For how long have "death and taxes" been accepted as a "certainty"?

Tags: idioms

The [**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=death+and+taxes&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeath%20and%20taxes%3B%2Cc0) shows usage of the phrase "death and taxes" from about 1760 and increasingly thereafter, with no sign of its increasing use diminishing in the near future.

The History of Taxation ([**Wikipedi**a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_taxation_in_the_United_Kingdom#Background)) states :

> Prior to the formation of the United Kingdom in 1707, taxation had been levied in the countries that joined to become the UK. For example, in England, King John introduced an export tax on wool in 1203 and King Edward I introduced taxes on wine in 1275.

The earliest statements regarding "death and taxes" (that I have yet found) are recorded in [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_taxes_(idiom)) :-

> "'Tis impossible to be sure of any thing but Death and Taxes,"

The Cobbler of Preston by Christopher Bullock (1716)

> Things as certain as death and taxes, can be more firmly believ'd.

Daniel Defoe, The Political History of the Devil, 1726.

> Our new Constitution is now established, and has an appearance that promises permanency; but in this world nothing can be said to be certain, except death and taxes.

Benjamin Franklin, in a letter to Jean-Baptiste Leroy, 1789

---

Comment: Are you looking to antedate the Wikipedia quotes on _death and taxes_, or are you looking for the oldest occurrence of taxation in history? The second is off-topic here, but may be interesting to ask on [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/). Having both questions here together seems to make this one too broad though...

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, accepted. I have edited out the history bit and just left an enquiry about the idiom, whether there are earlier references than Wiki. Thanks.

Comment: I like this question.  I'll bet people were using this phrase in the time of Hammurabi  c. 1810 BC – c. 1750 BC.   Or earlier.

Comment: Uu… beggar! I was bout to cit Hammurabi and ab2 got there first. Beggar!

Comment: I am waiting, with bated breath, for someone - possibly @ab2 - to tell me all about Hammurabi in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple explanation from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tax-words-glossary).

Note that this sentence might have foreign origins or influences as well. The sentence:

> Nihil morte certius

("nothing is more certain than death") was a Latin topos in medieval times.

It was  complemented by:

> et nihil incertius hora

"and nothing is more uncertain than the hour"

This usage has to be understood in the Medieval Christian perception of "God's will", as well as a wide range of opportunities to die unexpectedly.

There is surprisingly little material available on it, but a little research revealed that it is the opening sentence of a work of the 4th Century, [Saint-Augustine's *De contritione cordis*](https://books.google.ch/books?id=xldFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1373&lpg=PA1373&dq=%22nihil%20morte%20certius%22%20%22hora%20mortis%22&source=bl&ots=IgkPHOnoM0&sig=7YmzDRm_wAQZRMlJEekONWvHb3E&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6rIm0lZbbAhXE6qQKHfZjDQc4ChDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&q=%22nihil%20morte%20certius%22%20%22hora%20mortis%22&f=false) (I,1). Here is [more information on that work](http://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/04z/z_0354-0430__Augustinus__De_Contritione_Cordis__MLT.pdf.html).

The concept existed, of course, in classical Antiquity: see Cicero *De senectute* XX.74 (*Moriendum enim certe est*).

Adding taxes in a Modern, more secular era may have been a humorous way to oppose the necessity of both **natural law** (death) and **human law** (taxes). In that perspective, it might be be understood either as moral precept ("pay your taxes, it's the law") or an imprecation against the rapacity of the state.

Indeed, we can find a similar opposition between the natural and human planes, in the Italian saying:

> Piove, governo ladro.

litterally: "It rains; the government is stealing."

Though there might not be any linguistic connection with the English expression, it is an interesting convergence. In that particular case, there is no doubt about the meaning.

Comment: Contribution appreciated @fralau. If you would like to add online links to your Latin references I will up-vote and accept as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and for encouraging me to go a little further. I amended my answer.